# LocalTime deserialization error

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, rest

When deserializing `LocalTime` time in Spring, I encountered problem.

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '{"hour":9,"minute":0,"second":0,"nano":0}' could not be parsed at index 0

Here is the my code:

```
@Override
public Office deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
        DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {


    ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);    

    office.setOpenFrom(LocalTime.parse(node.get("openFrom").toString()));

    return office;
}
```

I send values by this method:

```
@Test
public void readSingleBookmark() throws Exception {
    RestTemplate tmp = new RestTemplate();

    Office office = new Office();
    office.setOpenFrom(LocalTime.parse("09:00"));

    tmp.postForLocation("http://localhost:8080/register",office);
}
```

Comment: what is your error ?

Comment: @maazza I just wrote the error